# Execute command in CMD prompt by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm writing a PowerShell script that creates a user in PostgreSQL. Some of the steps in the script are:

1. Open CMD Window
2. execute first command

   ```
   SET PGPASSWORD=superPassword
   ```
3. execute second command

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\psql.exe --username postgres --command "CREATE USER Ivan WITH CREATEDB PASSWORD 'ivanPassword';"
   ```

I have a problem, I found only like:

```
cmd.exe /c "SET PGPASSWORD=superPassword"
```

But it didn't work. And I don't known how execute both commands in one opened Command Prompt window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/110740) to a similar question on DBA StackExchange:

```
Set-Location 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin'
$env:PGPASSWORD = 'superPassword'
& .\psql.exe --% --username postgres --command "CREATE USER Ivan WITH CREATEDB PASSWORD 'ivanPassword';"
```

Note that the [stop-parsing symbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) (`--%`) requires PowerShell v3 or newer.

Comment: Certainly the best way to do this - no need to use CMD when PowerShell can run the commands natively.

Answer (score 1):

From the `cmd.exe` help:

> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
>   /K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains

Change your script to execute `cmd.exe /K cd c:\temp` and you're good to go.

Comment: And how powershell can execute another command in prompt window?

Comment: Once Powershell has started the command prompt window, it can't shove more into that prompt to execute.  But as was suggested in the comment on your original post, you're probably taking the wrong approach to whatever it is that you're attempting to do.